# Need to read and then remove duplicates from multiple CSV file in Spark scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I am new to this space,I have multiple partitioned CSV files having duplicates records. I want to read the CSV file in Spark Scala code and remove duplicates as well while reading.

I have tried `dropDuplicate()` and `read.format("csv")` with load option.

```
var df1 = thesparksession.read.format("csv").option("delimiter","|").option("header",true).load("path/../../*csv)
.withcolumn(col1)
df1.dropDuplicates().show()
```

if lets say csv1 has values

```
emp1 1000 nuu -1903.33
emp2 1003 yuu 1874.44
```

and csv2 has

```
emp1 1000 nuu -1903.33
emp4 9848 hee 1874.33
```

I need only one record with emp1 will be processed further.

expected output :

```
emp1 1000 nuu -1903.33
emp2 1003 yuu 1874.44
emp4 9848 hee 1874.33
```

Comment: CSV is usually delimited by `,` example : `emp1,1000,nuu,-1903.33`.
Are your columns in CSV delimited by `\t`  Tab space?

Comment: It is delimited by pipe

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input data the CSV columns are delimited by a pipe, to read the CSV into a data frame you can do

```
 var df1 = sparkSession.read.option("delimiter","|").csv(filePath)
```

//Drop duplicates

```
   val result = df1.dropDuplicates

   result.show
```

Output is:

```
    +----+----+---+--------+
    | _c0| _c1|_c2|     _c3|
    +----+----+---+--------+
    |emp1|1000|nuu|-1903.33|
    |emp4|9848|hee| 1874.33|
    |emp2|1003|yuu| 1874.44|
    +----+----+---+--------+
```

Comment: It is delimited by pipe

Answer (score 0):

```
dropDuplicates()
```

works perfect.

```
val sourcecsv = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").csv("path/../../*csv")
sourcecsv.show()

+-----+-----+----+--------+
|empid|idnum|name|  credit|
+-----+-----+----+--------+
| emp1| 1000| nuu|-1903.33|
| emp2| 1003| yuu| 1874.44|
| emp4| 9848| hee| 1874.33|
| emp1| 1000| nuu|-1903.33|
| emp2| 1003| yuu| 1874.44|
+-----+-----+----+--------+


//dropDuplicates() on a dataframe works perfect as expected
sourcecsv.dropDuplicates().show()

+-----+-----+----+--------+
|empid|idnum|name|  credit|
+-----+-----+----+--------+
| emp1| 1000| nuu|-1903.33|
| emp4| 9848| hee| 1874.33|
| emp2| 1003| yuu| 1874.44|
+-----+-----+----+--------+
```

Please let us know if there is any other issue.